# MultiThread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new in Android and even Java.
I have to save and read message in an activity using another class "Utility". And it will cause ANR, I heard I have to do that kind of things in a separate thread.
this is my code:

```
Utility.save(this, message, lsn);
Message tmp = Utility.read(this, lsn);
```

and I tried this:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
        this, "Please wait....", "Here your message");
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Utility.save(this, message, lsn);
    Message tmp = Utility.read(this, lsn);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}).start();
```

and as you can imagine, there is no way go just like this.
Do I need to use aidl?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you should probably do is use `AsyncTask` which is the Android way of multi threading in apps.

try reading in the android developers on this: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 1):

no, `Service` (or `IntentService`) or `AsyncTask` will do the job properly, please consider to read more about it at http://developer.android.com

Comment: Service alone won't do the job, because it run's on UI thread. It should be "Service and AsyncTask".